# Calling PHP file from JQuery to check unique identifier

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, postgresql

I'm trying to do this http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/

to check the avaliability of some id's while the user is filling some forms, but I'm using postgresql instead of mysql... I dont know what I'm doing wrong but I think there is something wrong with my php file and it must be a small error that I can't see since I'm trying to make an alert from it and nothing happens and I always get "instituto is not avaliable" even when it is avaliable (I tried to change the order from the returns 1 to 0 and vice-versa in the php file) and still, the same response. It seems like the php is not doing anything.

If you could help me, I'd be very thankful. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<input id="nombre_insti" class="widearea" type="text" name="nombre"> 
        </div>
        <div id='avaliability'>   </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var checking_html = 'Checking...';

    $('#nombre_insti').change(function(){
            $('#avaliability').html(checking_html);
            check_availability();
    });
});


function check_availability(){

    //get the instituto
    var instituto = $('#nombre_insti').val();

    //use ajax to run the check
    $.post("check.php", { instituto: instituto },
        function(result){
            //if the result is 1
            if(result == 1){
                //show that the instituto is available
                $('#avaliability').html(instituto + ' is Available');
            }else{
                //show that the instituto is NOT available
                $('#avaliability').html(instituto + ' is not Available');
            }
    });

}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $nombre_insti=$_POST['nombre_insti'];
    $result = pg_query("SELECT nombre_institucion 
                        FROM instituciones
                        WHERE
                        nombre_institucion='$nombre_insti'");
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("This alert is not showing");</script>

    if(pg_num_rows($result)==0){
        echo 0;
        return 0;
    }else{
        echo 1;
        return 1;
    }
}?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">alert("This alert is not showing");</script>` in the middle of a PHP file would never work without ?><script...><?... Also what is the return doing? It is not a method

Comment: where do you connect to the db?

Comment: Simple debugging technique: change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and open `check.php?nombre_insti=test` in your browser. You will see that there is a syntax error in your PHP script.

Comment: I'm connecting the db. I just wont paste the whole thing! I'm going to try the $_REQUEST thingy, give me a sec :)

Comment: First: your PHP code is incorrec as @mplungjan said. 
`<? PHP code ?><script .. ><? PHP code ?>`
Second: you PHP code will be generate answer `<script ...>0` or `<script .. >1` but you expect `0` or `1` . Move your alert to JS code `function(result) { alert(..); if(result == 1){ ...`

Comment: @Granola There's no need for it anymore; phpisuber01 already pointed you to the syntax error. My comment was meant as an advice for future problems that arise when dealing with AJAX.

Comment: furas and oswald you just made me realize a mistake that solved all my problems.. how can I mark a comment as the chosen response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$nombre_insti=$_POST['instituto'];
```

And remove the js code inside PHP script

Comment: I got that wrong. honorable mention to Oswald, mplungjan, and foras. for helping me to solve other issues.

Comment: @Granola, the way to honor helpers on StackOverflow is to upvote their comments (or answers).

Answer (score 1):

If your getting no response, it's because you have a fatal PHP error and you have `display_errors` turned off.

The cause of the error is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("This alert is not showing");</script>
```

You have HTML in the middle of your PHP.

You can correct it by using `echo` or closing the PHP tags around the HTML.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This alert is not showing");</script>';
```

or

```
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("This alert is not showing");</script>
<?php
```

Comment: `display_errors` does not enter into it, because the page is accessed via AJAX.

Comment: OP described his PHP "is not doing anything", assuming he is getting a blank response, that's indicative of `display_errors`.

Comment: Actually the OP says it *seems* PHP is not doing anything, because the JavaScript always produces *the same response*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) of the validation plugin

```
var rp = "<?php echo base_path; ?>";
var validator = $("#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "firstname" : {
            required : true                    
        }, 
        "lastname" : {
            required : true                    
        },
        "email" : {
            required : true,
            email : true, 
            remote: rp + 'user/emailExists'
        },
        "username" : {
            required : true,
            remote: rp + 'user/usernameExists'          
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "username" : {
                remote : jQuery.format("username not Available")
           },
        "email" : {
            remote : jQuery.format("email not Available")
        }
    }
});
```